# method in the class returns null instead of a string retrieved via async call

Tags: java, android

Utils.java

```
/**
 * Created by faiz on 15/08/17.
 */

package com.example.android.whereabouts;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;



public class Utils {
    private String apiresponse;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public  Utils(String url){
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("exception",e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                apiresponse = response.body().string();
                Log.e("onResponse",apiresponse);
            }
        });

    }

    public String getData(){
        if(apiresponse != null)
        return apiresponse ;
        else
            return "error";

    }

}
```

When i instantiate this class in my main activity and try to Log return value of getData method, it logs "error" instead of the value of variable *apiresponse* .

Its obvious that that it takes some time to get response from the server and *getData* call gets executed before the server returns a response.

So how to make sure getData gets called after onResponse has been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two workarounds which I'll share here and I request the people who answered this question to share their thoughts on this.(I appreciate the answers shared on this question..thanks to you all )
Note: Its more of a "clean code question" than "how to get this thing to work question"

Solution 1:

We can wait till the onResponse method gets called in getData() like this

```
while(true)
 if(apiresponse!=null)
  return(apiresponse);
```

to make sure this is not an indefinite while loop we set the variable *apiresponse* to something in both onResponse and OnFailure methods(either one will surely get executed) to break the loop.

this one seems to work but its pretty naive to me to use infinite loop and break it.

Solution 2:

Writing an AsyncTask and the Executing Utils class in the doInBackground method of that async task.

(I think the second approach makes sense as it falls under standard practices of android so it makes the thing work and also satisfies the best practices).

Another thing: an obvious question to some would be that when you're ready to write the whole async task inside the activity, then why is it an issue to write the Utils.java code directly inside the activity. My response to that is , despite of writing the asynctask in the activity, its better because it saves me from manually handling Handlers to create another thread inside onResponse to update the UI and it also falls under standard practices . So I think this approach makes more sense overall.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting a callback in Utility, You can implement that in your Activity so that call back will come to ur activity and you can update in UI without any issue.

```
public  Utils(String url, Callback callback){
    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);

}
```

in your actvity, you can call like,

```
public void getdata() {
   new Utils("[url]",  new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("exception",e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                apiresponse = response.body().string();
                Log.e("onResponse",apiresponse);
                // here you can show in UI.
            }
        })
}
```

or you can create a separate custom interface and you can do same after getting the response from the server.

Comment: My purpose for doing this is to keep the implimentation of networking  away from the activity class.Otherwise I could have added the complete code in the activity itself.

Comment: In this also you are doing Network in different class only, You are just adding the listener her, And in my answer also I mentioned, If you do not prefer this way, you can create your custom interface and you can give callback same like this. because this is a utility class so, you cant take any class as a reference and call the method.

Comment: You can check others answer too they will refer the only interface.

Comment: After some pondering and looking up I am posting an answer myself and I would like to have you guys' perspective on that too. If it makes sense to you then I'll mark mine one as accepted otherwise it'll be this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a callback mechanism and call the callback method from inside the `onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response)` method.

Here is an example. You should define this in the Utils class -

```
public interface Callback {
   void getData(String data);
}

private Callback callback;
```

In the constructor pass in the activity reference when you instantiate the Utils class.

```
// In the activity
utilsInstance = new Utils(url, this);

// In your Utils class
public  Utils(String url, Callback activityCallback) {
  callback = activityCallback
}
```

In your activity, you need to implement this interface -

```
public class RetrofitActivity implements Utils.Callback {
   @Override
   public void getData(String data) {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

And in your `OnResponse()` method, you'll call this method like so -

```
             @Override
             public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                apiresponse = response.body().string();
                callback.getData(apiresponse);
                Log.e("onResponse",apiresponse);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : In Utils method pass calling activity as below

```
    public Utils(CallingActivity activity , String url)
    {
       Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
       okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(activity);
    }
```

Step 2 : Implement Callback of OkHttpClient in your calling activity.

Step 3 : Override onFailure() and onResponse() of OkHttpClient and call Utils(this,url) in calling activity.